# Guessing game, 1 to 100 using do/while loop and if/ese if conditional statement

Tags: javascript, if-statement, do-while

I am trying to make a guessing game with simple java script. the professor gave us a guide, but i am still a bit confused. Based on the guide, we are to use a do/while loop, and within that loop, use the if/else if conditional statement, here is what i have so far.
i've tried changing it so many times, and all i end up with is a never ending loop, even after the number is guessed, it doesnt stop

```
<body>
    <p>
        I'm thinking of a number between 1 and 100, try to guess it! </br>

        <script>
            var number = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100 + 1)
        //guess variable to store the guessed number by user
            var guess 
        //output to store output to the user
            var output 
        //if the user guessed the number or not, initialize it to false
            var guessed = false

        //do/while loop, while condition is based on if the user NOT guessing the number (e.g. guessed == false)
        do {
            guess = prompt ("Think of a number between 1 and 100, what is your number?");
            document.write ("You guessed the number " + guess + "<br/>");
            if (guess > number) {
                document.write ("You guessed too high, think smaller" + "<br/>");
                guessed = false
                }
            else if (guess < number){
                document.write ("You guessed too low, think bigger" + "<br/");
                guessed = false
                }
            else {
                alert("You guessed the right number!")
                guessed = true}
        }
        while (guessed = false) 


        </script>
    </p>
</body>
```

Comment: `=` is an assignment. `==` and `===` are comparison

Comment: `=` is assignment, `==` is equality. You need to change it to `while (guessed == false)`. Right now, you're setting it to `false` on every loop. You could also simplify it to `while (!guessed)` by using the "not" (`!`) operator.

Comment: ok, so i did that and it worked, thanks! Now, how do i get it to stop? After the user guesses the number it just goes back to making him/her guess again without picking a new number

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're missing a ton of semi-colons which should be added though your code will still run without them. And like everyone else said you are assigning `guessed` to `false` at the end of your `do while loop`, therefore it will never break out. To check a condition you should use 3 equal signs (this is strict comparison). More on that [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/523643/difference-between-and-in-javascript). It is debatable if `document.write` should be used. Reason for that can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/802854/why-is-document-write-considered-a-bad-practice). Also, when testing your code it worked intermittently, so I added a div with the `id` of hints. Then I grabbed that element with `var elHints = document.getElementById('#hints');` Then to add content to the `element` hints simply do `elHints.textContent += ...`. The plus equals (`+=`) adds content to the element without overwriting existing content. In css I added a style to `#hints`: `white-space: pre-line;` this allows line breaks (`\n`) to the `div` when adding content using `textContent`. More on that [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21033887/preserving-newlines-when-using-text-or-textcontent-possible-alternatives).

Here is the full javascript code:

```
var number = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100 + 1);
//guess variable to store the guessed number by user
var guess;
//output to store output to the user
var output;
//if the user guessed the number or not, initialize it to false
var guessed = false;
var elHints = document.getElementById('hints');

//do/while loop, while condition is based on if the user NOT guessing the number (e.g. guessed == false)
do {
  guess = prompt("Think of a number between 1 and 100, what is your number?");
  elHints.textContent += "You guessed the number " + guess + '\n';
  if (guess > number) {
    elHints.textContent += "You guessed too high, think smaller" + '\n';
    guessed = false;
  } else if (guess < number) {
    elHints.textContent += "You guessed too low, think bigger" + '\n';
    guessed = false;
  } else {
    alert("You guessed the right number!")
    guessed = true;
  }
}
while (guessed === false);
```

And here's the [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mhy2f7ch/5/).

Answer (score 0):

I believe that you are missing a semi-colon here :

```
while(guessed == false);
```

This is just an requirement specific to the do-while loop and does not occur in the syntax for other loops.

Answer (score 0):

Your code has some issues.

First of all you need to change `while (guessed = false)` into `while (guessed === false)` because it should be a comparision, hence you have to use a comparator.

Secondly, you are using `document.write()`. This will not work, because the HTML won't change until the user breaks out of the loop. It would be a good idea to use `alert()` instead. Here is a working example:

```js
var number = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100 + 1)
  //guess variable to store the guessed number by user
var guess
  //output to store output to the user
var output
  //if the user guessed the number or not, initialize it to false
var guessed = false

//do/while loop, while condition is based on if the user NOT guessing the number (e.g. guessed == false)
do {
  guess = prompt("Think of a number between 1 and 100, what is your number?");
  if (guess > number) {
    alert("You guessed too high, think smaller");
    guessed = false
  } else if (guess < number) {
    alert("You guessed too low, think bigger");
    guessed = false
  } else {
    alert("You guessed the right number!")
    guessed = true
  }
}
while (guessed === false)
```

Answer (score 0):

In your condition at while(guessed = false) you use one equal-signe (=), witch is forever true. you must write (guessed == false) or (guessed === false). for trying i would do ist so:

I'm thinking of a number between 1 and 100, try to guess it!

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var number = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100 + 1);
    // Just for Test
    document.getElementById('test').innerHTML += '<br />' + number;
    //guess variable to store the guessed number by user
    var guess;
    //output to store output to the user
    var output;
    //if the user guessed the number or not, initialize it to false
    var guessed = false;

    //do/while loop, while condition is based on if the user NOT guessing the number (e.g. guessed == false)
    do {
        guess = prompt("Think of a number between 1 and 100, what is your number?");
        document.getElementById('test').innerHTML += '<br />' + "You guessed the number " + guess;
        if (guess > number) {
            document.getElementById('test').innerHTML += '<br />' + "You guessed too high, think smaller";
            guessed = false;
        }
        else if (guess < number) {
            document.getElementById('test').innerHTML += '<br />' + "You guessed too low, think bigger";
            guessed = false;
        }
        else {
            alert("You guessed the right number!")
            guessed = true;
        }
    }
    while (guessed == false)
</script>
```